# Override an external applications maximize command

Tags: c#, .net, api

Using C#, I am looking to hook into the Windows API (I'm not sure which one) to capture which windows are being sent a maximize command.  I want to then override that command to tell the window what the bound of the maximized window should be.

For example, when a user maximizes Notepad on an 800x600 screen, I want to specify the size that the window actually expands to.  I might tell Notepad to "maximize" to 600x600 starting at position 200,0.

For this solution, it isn't necessary that the window actually believe it is maximized, I just want to control the window so it doesn't maximize to the whole screen (or that it restores itself automatically to the size I want if that is the best I can do).

As I stated, I want to control external applications (Notepad, Word, etc.) not my own application.  I would prefer to write this application in C#.  The actions I need to perform are:

- Capture maximize (or resize) events
- Readjust the changed window's size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be hooking into the windows Message Loops ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for documentation on the APIs you need). Overall, you'll either be doing a ton of P\Invokes, or you'll want to use C and the raw Win32 APIs.

I'm not certain, but I believe you will want to start by using a Windows Hook: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That is basically what I worked on. I got a semi-working solution that basically loops through all of the currently-open windows and ensures they are only maximized to a certain size.  Then I listened for the changes to other applications and I made sure again that they weren't too large.  It is a kludge but it works.